# Web Browsers Showing Error Page

Tags: c#, fiddler

I never used fiddler core before. But after first time using it into my application, a weird problem is happening. Whenever my application is running web browsers are working fine. But other time those all showing error page. I know I did something wrong with fiddler core. I am sending my codes here. Codes are working perfectly. But there is something into my code so that I getting this problem. Please see the code and let me know what am I doing wrong.

```
    static bool bUpdateTitle = true;
    static Proxy oSecureEndpoint;
    static string sSecureEndpointHostname = "localhost";
    static int iSecureEndpointPort = 1106;

    private void button1_Click(object senderr, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Fiddler.Session> oAllSessions = new List<Fiddler.Session>();
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.OnNotification += delegate(object sender, NotificationEventArgs oNEA) { MessageBox.Show("** NotifyUser: " + oNEA.NotifyString); };

        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += delegate(Fiddler.Session oS)
        {
            oS.bBufferResponse = false;
            Monitor.Enter(oAllSessions);
            oAllSessions.Add(oS);
            Monitor.Exit(oAllSessions);

            if (oS.hostname=="localhost")
            {
                oS.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
                oS.oResponse.headers.HTTPResponseStatus = "200 Ok";
                oS.oResponse["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
                oS.oResponse["Cache-Control"] = "private, max-age=0";
                oS.utilSetResponseBody("<html><body><font size=10>Restricted</font></body></html>");
            }
        };
        Fiddler.CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = false;
        FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetBoolPref("fiddler.network.streaming.abortifclientaborts", true);
        FiddlerCoreStartupFlags oFCSF = FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default;
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(0, oFCSF);
        oSecureEndpoint = FiddlerApplication.CreateProxyEndpoint(iSecureEndpointPort, true, sSecureEndpointHostname);
    }
    public static void DoQuit()
    {
        if (null != oSecureEndpoint) oSecureEndpoint.Dispose();
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DoQuit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the response to your same message left in the Fiddler discussion group, this means that you ran your program at least once without properly calling Shutdown() (e.g. because it crashed). Clear the incorrect proxy settings from Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings when your program isn't running.